# Maximum threads limit per process in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, threads

I have a programs that works with threads. I want to know what is the maximum threads limit per process in windows 10 or what is the maximum threads windows 10 can handle?

Comment: There isn’t a single processor on the market that exceeds the current limit.  Any limit would be with the software itself.  Consumer versions of Windows only support up to 2 processors

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/testlimit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll hit other problems rather than any explicit cap. [As explained by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773), every thread requires some memory for bookkeeping, notably its stack (where the thread is in its execution of the program). 32-bit processes can only address 4 GB of memory, which will fit about 2,000 threads with the default 1 MB stack allocation per thread or about 12,000 with the smallest possible allocation of 64 KB per thread. 64-bit processes don't have problems with address space, but rather with the actual allocations. My system runs out of memory a little after `testlimit64 -t` passes 270,000 threads created.

However, programs should not approach any such limit or need to worry about it. Quoting the previously linked post (with broken links fixed):

> The “one thread per client” model is well-known not to scale beyond
>   a dozen clients or so. If you’re going to be handling more than that
>   many clients simultaneously, you should move to a model where
>   instead of dedicating a thread to a client, you instead allocate
>   an object. [...]
>   Windows provides [I/O completion ports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) and [a thread pool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pools) to help you convert from a thread-based model to a work-item-based model.